# Laravel 5.4 + Vue.js 2.0 how to wrap js components into laravel app

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, components, vuejs2

So basically my problem is, how to wrap vue components to laravel app. Its quite big website build on laravel blade templating. My question is, if i should wrap whole website in a single app element, and then add components in a way similar to this:

```
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">

    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <title>@yield('description')</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="vue-app-wrapper" id="app">
      <div class="container">
        <some-vue-component1></some-vue-component1>
      </div>

      <div class="content-wrapper">
        @yield('content')
      </div>

      <footer style="margin-top: 30px;">
        <!-- some footer stuff -->
      </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    @stack('scripts')
  </body>
</html>
```

And just include another components in other sections.
Or maybe i should build multiple vue apps, wrap smaller elements and push required js files through laravel blade @stack and @push. I would like to know advantages and disadvantages of both soultions, also i wonder if VUE is suited for what i will use JS for. Main purpose of vue scripts are some dynamic ajax calls like "add to favourites", "rate item" etc. Alsto some carouseles, searcher and creating localStorage data. Maybe i should use vanilajs/jquery?

Comment: Do provide your `app.js` file as it contains the configuration for your Vue components.

Comment: My question is, if i should provide one big app.js file, that contain all of my VUE scripts including vue itself, and wrap whole body content in #app element and include only components where it is necessary, or should i wrap only necessary elements as an apps, and than import multiple vue apps files through blade template, only while section requires so.

Comment: Yes. You should be doing that.

Comment: Me: Should i go A or B?
You: Yes

Comment: Sorry. I was referring to this "if i should provide one big app.js file, that contain all of my VUE scripts including vue itself, and wrap whole body content in #app element and include only components where it is necessary". And yes, this is the preferred method.